# AngularJS injecting duplicate $$hashkey and causing error

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I don't know why suddenly this began but for the life of me I can't figure it out.  This code has been working and now suddenly I am getting this.

In my $q.all() statement I am processing all the returned results and assigning them to a new array.  After the processing is done I print the new array to console and see a duplicate entry in my results.

```
var newResults = [] ;
return $q.all([promise1(),promise2(),promise3(),promise4()])
.then(function(response) {  // response is an array of arrays of objects
  // flatten results
  var z=0 ;
  for (var y=0;y<response.length;y++) {  //array of all results
    for (var x=0;x<response[y].length;x++) {  // array of each result
      newResults.push(response[y][x]) ;
      console.log(newResults[z]) ;
      z++ ;
    }
  }
  console.log("SHOW RESULTS") ;
  console.log(newResults) ;
}) ;
```

Notice, there is literally nothing between the two console.log statements that changes or alters the array.  But look at the outputs below:

```
{vendorID: 0, vendor: "Company AAA", serviceType: 0, serviceSwitch: 1, serviceClass: "standard", …}
{vendorID: 1, vendor: "Company AAA", serviceType: 0, serviceSwitch: 1, serviceClass: "standard", …}
{vendorID: 2, vendor: "Company AAA", serviceType: 0, serviceSwitch: 1, serviceClass: "standard", …}
{vendorID: 3, vendor: "Company AAA", serviceType: 0, serviceSwitch: 1, serviceClass: "standard", …}
{vendorID: 4, vendor: "Company AAA", serviceType: 0, serviceSwitch: 1, serviceClass: "standard", …}
{vendorID: 5, vendor: "Company AAA", serviceType: 0, serviceSwitch: 1, serviceClass: "enhanced", …}
{vendorID: 6, vendor: "Company AAA", serviceType: 0, serviceSwitch: 1, serviceClass: "standard", …}
{vendorID: 7, vendor: "Company AAA", serviceType: 0, serviceSwitch: 1, serviceClass: "standard", …}
{vendorID: 8, vendor: "Company AAA", serviceType: 0, serviceSwitch: 2, serviceClass: "standard", …}
{vendorID: 9, serviceType: 0, vendor: "Company BBB", serviceSwitch: 1, serviceClass: "standard", …}
{vendorID: 10, serviceType: 0, vendor: "Company BBB", serviceSwitch: 1, serviceClass: "standard", …}
{vendorID: 11, serviceType: 0, vendor: "Company BBB", serviceSwitch: 1, serviceClass: "enhanced", …}
{vendorID: 12, serviceType: 0, vendor: "Company BBB", serviceSwitch: 1, serviceClass: "vip", …}
{vendorID: 13, serviceType: 0, vendor: "Company BBB", serviceSwitch: 1, serviceClass: "standard", …}
{vendorID: 14, serviceType: 0, vendor: "Company BBB", serviceSwitch: 1, serviceClass: "standard", …}
{vendorID: 15, serviceType: 0, vendor: "Company DDD", serviceSwitch: 0, product_id: "N/A", …}
{vendorID: 16, serviceType: 0, vendor: "Company FFF", serviceSwitch: 0, product_id: "N/A", …}
{vendorID: 17, serviceType: 0, vendor: "Company GGG", serviceSwitch: 0, product_id: "N/A", …}
{vendorID: 18, serviceType: 1, vendor: "Company HHH", serviceSwitch: 1, service_type: 1, …}
{vendorID: 19, serviceType: 0, vendor: "Company III", serviceSwitch: 0, product_id: "N/A", …}
{vendorID: 20, serviceType: 0, vendor: "Company CCC", serviceSwitch: 1, serviceClass: "standard", …}
{vendorID: 21, serviceType: 0, vendor: "Company CCC", serviceSwitch: 1, serviceClass: "enhanced", …}
{vendorID: 22, serviceType: 0, vendor: "Company JJJ", serviceSwitch: 0, product_id: "N/A", …}
{vendorID: 23, serviceType: 0, vendor: "Company KKK", serviceSwitch: 0, product_id: "N/A", …}
{vendorID: 24, serviceType: 0, vendor: "Company LLL", serviceSwitch: 0, product_id: "N/A", …}
```

In the above, when I expand each object there are NO $$hashkey's assigned to any of objects.

```
SHOW RESULTS

0:{vendorID: 20, serviceType: 0, vendor: "Company CCC", serviceSwitch: 1, serviceClass: "standard", …}
1:{vendorID: 10, serviceType: 0, vendor: "Company BBB", serviceSwitch: 1, serviceClass: "standard", …}
2:{vendorID: 3, vendor: "Company AAA", serviceType: 0, serviceSwitch: 1, serviceClass: "standard", …}
3:{vendorID: 1, vendor: "Company AAA", serviceType: 0, serviceSwitch: 1, serviceClass: "standard", …}
4:{vendorID: 8, vendor: "Company AAA", serviceType: 0, serviceSwitch: 2, serviceClass: "standard", …}
5:{vendorID: 7, vendor: "Company AAA", serviceType: 0, serviceSwitch: 1, serviceClass: "standard", …}
6:{vendorID: 0, vendor: "Company AAA", serviceType: 0, serviceSwitch: 1, serviceClass: "standard", …}
7:{vendorID: 0, vendor: "Company AAA", serviceType: 0, serviceSwitch: 1, serviceClass: "standard", …}
8:{vendorID: 11, serviceType: 0, vendor: "Company BBB", serviceSwitch: 1, serviceClass: "enhanced", …}
9:{vendorID: 5, vendor: "Company AAA", serviceType: 0, serviceSwitch: 1, serviceClass: "enhanced", …}
10:{vendorID: 21, serviceType: 0, vendor: "Company CCC", serviceSwitch: 1, serviceClass: "enhanced", …}
11:{vendorID: 18, serviceType: 1, vendor: "Company HHH", serviceSwitch: 1, service_type: 1, …}
12:{vendorID: 12, serviceType: 0, vendor: "Company BBB", serviceSwitch: 1, serviceClass: "vip", …}
13:{vendorID: 12, serviceType: 0, vendor: "Company BBB", serviceSwitch: 1, serviceClass: "vip", …}
14:{vendorID: 4, vendor: "Company AAA", serviceType: 0, serviceSwitch: 1, serviceClass: "standard", …}
15:{vendorID: 13, serviceType: 0, vendor: "Company BBB", serviceSwitch: 1, serviceClass: "standard", …}
16:{vendorID: 6, vendor: "Company AAA", serviceType: 0, serviceSwitch: 1, serviceClass: "standard", …}
17:{vendorID: 14, serviceType: 0, vendor: "Company BBB", serviceSwitch: 1, serviceClass: "standard", …}
18:{vendorID: 19, serviceType: 0, vendor: "Company III", serviceSwitch: 0, product_id: "N/A", …}
19:{vendorID: 17, serviceType: 0, vendor: "Company GGG", serviceSwitch: 0, product_id: "N/A", …}
20:{vendorID: 24, serviceType: 0, vendor: "Company LLL", serviceSwitch: 0, product_id: "N/A", …}
21:{vendorID: 23, serviceType: 0, vendor: "Company KKK", serviceSwitch: 0, product_id: "N/A", …}
22:{vendorID: 22, serviceType: 0, vendor: "Company JJJ", serviceSwitch: 0, product_id: "N/A", …}
23:{vendorID: 16, serviceType: 0, vendor: "Company FFF", serviceSwitch: 0, product_id: "N/A", …}
24:{vendorID: 15, serviceType: 0, vendor: "Company DDD", serviceSwitch: 0, product_id: "N/A", …}
```

See results after its says "SHOW RESULTS", array index 6 and 7 repeat...and when I expand those results I see the following, 6 & 7 $$hashkey's repeat, and then from result index 8 and on there are no $$hashkey's assigned.  Also, why would the angularJS rearrange the whole array in such a random order?

```
5:
  $$hashKey: "object:97"
  vendorID: 7
6:
  $$hashKey:"object:98"
  vendorID: 0 
  ...
7:
  $$hashKey:"object:98"
  vendorID: 0
8:
  vendorID: 11  
  ...
...
...
```

What in the world could be causing this?  And more importantly...how the heck do I fix it?

Comment: it's not really clear what other code you have that could be interacting with this code;  `$$hashKey` is generally added due to something like an `ng-repeat` or `ng-options` usage.  Also, you initialize the array, then do `$q.all`, which is async, and other code could modify the array before the async calls have returned. I would start with doing a log of your `newResults` array on the first line of the `.then` and verify that it is indeed empty.

Comment: I figured it out...

Comment: so what did it turn out to be? feel free to provide a self answer if you think it will help others avoid the same problem....

Comment: Sorry.  It was a double sort causing the problem, a sort inside of another sort creating a duplicate hashkey....a coding error.